# How to install speech_data in python

Tags: python, deep-learning, speech

I am new to Deep Learning and Speech Recognition domain. I am trying to install speech_data in pc but it gives me error as show in screeshot below:

[image]

It seems this library is being used to create 'batch' using this code in my sample assignment:

```
batch = word_batch = speech_data.mfcc_batch_generator(64)
```

I have searched a lot on internet but I could not not find any official website or any reference regarding how to download this library.